# How to redeclare function parameter if it is not actually passed into function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameters

What is the best way to redeclare a function parameter if it is not actually passed into the function?

```
function testVariable(foo, bar) {
    bar = bar ? bar : foo; // <--
    return bar;
};

const myFinalValue = testVariable("testValue");
```

I want to do this to ensure that `bar` has a value before I continue my automation (`return`, in this example).

Do I have to declare a new variable name or is it possible to overwrite the given parameter?

If I overwrite that parameter, will the overwritten variable become global if no value has been passed for that parameter into the function (per the example)?

Comment: Parameters work (in almost all normal cases) just like local variables. And no, the assignment will not create an implicit global, because it's already local to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Just use defaults, and then check if the variable is the default, if it is then do whatever you want

```js
function testVariable(foo, bar = foo) {
    return bar;
};

const myFinalValue = testVariable("testValue");
console.log(myFinalValue);
```

Comment: Can another parameter be set as a default? Like `function testVariable(foo, bar = foo)`?

Comment: Just answered my question. According to MDN, earlier parameters are available for defaulting. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Comment: Using `undefined` as the default is pointless. That's exactly the value that will fallback to the default.

Comment: @BenRogol sorry if I were not clear, yes, your thinking is correct.

Comment: @Bergi the undefined was for example purposes, I edited my answer to be more clear